# When to use AngularJS services instead of JavaScript native functions/objects?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS` and I am confused when to use them and why they were built if native `JavaScript` object could have served the purpose. The `AngularJS` services in question are `$location`, `$window`, `$document` etc.

Comment: These services are just encapsulation of Javascript objects location, window and document. My interpretation is just that it would be cleaner if you can inject them in your controller so you are aware of what it needs and does.

Comment: From the docs "While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable."

Comment: For $document it is just confort since it wraps it in a jquery variable: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document

Comment: when to use? always

Comment: @petr why?    ........

Answer (score 0):

Most of the services doesn't really do anything. For example $window is just window wrapped in  function and provider. But in a few cases you have to use services provided by AngularJS to remain in it's scope so your app can track changes. Any code that runs outside of AngularJS framework isn't tracked by it, so if you would use:

```
setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("This is outside AngularJS scope.");
     this.myName = "John";
}, 1000);
```

HTML binded to 'myName' wouldn't be updated. You'd have to call  $digest so AngularJS could refresh changes or wrap your code in $apply(() => { your code }). So that's why AngularJS provides these services. Which are just default functions provided by browser  but  wrapped in $apply function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary purposes of these services are for mocking or testing the application. They are also limited to the current scope so you don't have to worry about accidentally overwriting stuff in the global object.

Another small advantage is that dependencies when uglyfied are replaced while the global object window would stay the same.